# How do I recompile Python in VirtualEnv?

Tags: linux, centos, python, virtualenv

I built virtualenv and it adds Python 2.7 by default in it. After reading [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23208383/4127849) to a bug I have, it says I have to recompile Python with the option `--enable-shared`. So should I `rm -rf` Python from the virtualenv and download it again?